# Dynamically filter Vega visualisation

Tags: vega

I'd like to dynamically filter [this](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/vega/iaindillingham/69a33bf41ec9830b50e99b5d8d7a3358/86da705364feedce87725b381f2fa0f401adaa01/beeswarm_plot.json) Vega visualisation. At present, if you click an item in the legend, then symbols representing that item are highlighted. I'd like to modify it such that if you click an item in the legend, then sybmols representing that item are filtered (i.e. symbols not representing that item are removed). However, if you click the same item in the legend again, then the filter is cleared.

I've tried creating two datasets -- `table` and `filtered_table` -- but can't get the `source` property to work with the `on` property. I've also investigated the crossfilter transform, but this seems to be for continuous, rather than categorical, data.

Thanks in advance!